# Increase row height jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I've got some cells where the content is to big for the cell.

How can I adjust the height of the rows when the content doesnt fit in width?

Comment: Which kind of content you have? Do you use custom formatter for the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use text wrapping which described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006134/315935) (word wrapping) and in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6915486/315935) (char wrapping). I would recommend you additionally read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935) which described advantages and disadvantages the usage of the two ways of wrapping. In both approaches will be used

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    height: auto;
}
```

which can be helpful not only in case of text wrapping.