# How to wrap jqGrid content?

Tags: jqgrid

I want to wrap the content inside jqGrid which will be in the below format

```
Input string
2013/05/28 10:54 - Default - Subject A Task added

Output String 
2013/05/28 10:54 - Default 
Subject A Task added
```

Below is the code where I give the content to be displayed on screen

```js
jQuery("#message").jqGrid({
    datatype : "local",
    data : resultSet,
    height :250,
    width : 960,
    sortable : false,
    ignoreCase : true,
    sortorder : "desc",
    colNames : [''], 
    colModel : [ {
        name : 'content',
        index : 'content',
        width : '10%',
        align : 'center',   
        sortable : false,
        search : false
    }],
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager : '#pager',
    rowNum : 10,
    altRows : true,
    altclass:"myclass",
    viewrecords : true,

});
```

I tried `nltobr` like this

```js
loadComplete : function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i++) {
        resultSet[i].messageContent = nl2br(resultSet[i].messageContent);
    }
}
```

That is not working.

Is there any way to wrap based on second hipen? I also want to bold the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all [nltobr](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp) can be used in the *server* code and not inside of JavaScript callback method `loadComplete` will will be executed after filling the grid. Seconds the callback `loadComplete` will be called *after* the grid content will be placed in the grid. If you want make some modification of `resultSet` data you should do this *before* the grid with the data are created.

You wrote about wrapping of content, but the usage of `nltobr` and the text example which you posted shows that you have just new line character `\n` inside of the text. It it is

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NewLine.htm) uses the text which you posted and contains `\n` inside of the text. The results looks like you want

[image]

If you really need *wrapping* of the text then I recommend you to read the following answers: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6915486/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006134/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935).

**UPDATED**: If you need make bold the first line of multiline content of some column you can insert `<strong>` in the text. If you don't use `autoencode: true` option of jqGrid then you can modify input data *before* creating jqGrid. For example [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NewLine1.htm) modifies content of `note` column:

```js
var i, str, a;

for (i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
    str = mydata[i].note;
    if (typeof str === "string") {
        a = str.split("\n");
        if (a.length > 1) {
            a[0] = "<strong>" + a[0] + "</strong>";
            mydata[i].note = a.join("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

[Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NewLine2.htm) demonstrate how to use custom formatter to do the same. You should use the approach if you use `autoencode: true` option of jqGrid. Th formatter of `note` column are defined in the demo as

```js
formatter: function (value) {
    var a;
    if (value == null || value === "") {
        return "&#160;";
    } else if (typeof value === "string") {
        a = value.split("\n");
        if (a.length > 1) {
            a[0] = "<strong>" + a[0] + "</strong>";
            return a.join("\n");
        } else {
            return $.jgrid.htmlEncode(value);
        }
    } else {
        return $.jgrid.htmlEncode(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful guidance ...Thanks a lot. I just want to make bold the first line of a column. Any idea about it ?

Comment: @sahana: You are welcome! You don't use `autoencode: true` option, so jqGrid interpret all the data as HTML fragments which are inserted in the cells. So you can just modify input data `resultSet` like you want. You can for example use `split("\n")` to divide string in subtrings , then modify the first element of the array as `a[0] = "<strong>" + a[0] + "</strong>";` and then convert results back to string with `a.join("\n")`. You can use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) for the `content` column to do the same sransformations optionally.

Comment: I tried like this, alert(resultSet.length);for (var j=0; j<resultSet.length;j++){
   alert(resultSet.split("\n", 3));
  } But I got "Object Array has no split method." Is this correct way to apply Bold ? I also have doubt where to give that split and join.

Comment: @sahana: You should use correct code. `resultSet` is *array*, the item `resultSet[j]` should be *object* with `content` property. So you should use `var a = resultSet[j].content.split("\n"); a[0] = "<strong>" + a[0] + "</strong>"; resultSet[j].content = a.join("\n");`

Comment: oops!! okay i got it. I will try it out. Thank you

Comment: resultSet = data;
  for (var splitData = 0; splitData < resultSet.length; splitData++){
   var splitString = resultSet[splitData].content.split("\n");
   splitString[splitData] =  "<strong>" + splitString[splitData] + "</strong>";
   resultSet[splitData].content = splitString.join("\n");
  }  After this, for content display to grid, data : resultSet is given. Whether this is correct? I don't see bold content at all. Am I making mistake

Comment: @sahana: Everything is very easy. I created two demos which demonstrate how to can make bold the first line of multiline content. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.