# Wrapping text in JQGrid column using JSON data

Tags: json, jqgrid, word-wrap

I have a column in JQGrid that will contain a long string of text However the column is not wide enough to display the string in one line. I am using JSON data.

Is there a way to wrap this long line of text so that the entire string is displayed within my column ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there are some references to old answers about the same subject: [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006134/315935), [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6915486/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16787770/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8771429/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171924/315935).