# jQGrid With Multiple Row Data

Tags: jqgrid, multirow

I have a requirement to display a single jqgrid into several lines (2 or 3). The user does not want to use the grid horizontal scroll bar and would like to see several data at once.

Anybody with an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to wrap rows in the grid because the grid have large number or rows. It's not possible because jqGrid are base on HTML `<table>` and the row (`<tr>`) of table can't be wrapped.

If you have grid with columns which text is long you can consider wrapping **inside of cells** of grid. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6915486/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006134/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16787770/315935) too.

Comment: Thanks @oleg I think dojo or dgrid is the way to go for customized grid.