# IE9 Does Not Understand Overriden CSS Property

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've overridden a CSS property of at my HTML page however IE9 can not display it well. When I debug the CSS I get that:

[image: before]

as you see white-space is overriden. However it does not work as intended. When I explicitly uncheck the white-space property of jqGrid as follows:

[image: after]

it works as intended. Any ideas?

**PS:** The code I've used:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
        word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ and CSS3 */
        white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 */
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
        white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
        overflow: hidden;
        height: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: add !important after the properties

Comment: please attach code to your question

Comment: @Evgeniy I've attached the code. However my question is not related to code?

Comment: actually it does, as i can see you have 2 same by specificity rules, one external CSS second internal table. Internal table has higher priority then external, so there is no sense uncheck rule in section of external file as it overwritten in internal section. If you uncheck internal section (startup.do) you will see result

Comment: @Evgeniy I uncheck internal section (startup.do) and nothing happens. When I uncheck jqgrid section it works as I explained.

Comment: @TusharGupta !important did not work.