# Capture width of columns of a grid at runtime

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, struts2-jquery

I want to capture width of columns (which are resizable) in my grid..the plugin i am using is struts2-jquery plugin.all this should happen at runtime.As soon as the width of any of the columns are changed the width should be captured..

Answer (score 0):

You should use `resizeStop` callback or `jqGridResizeStop` event (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events)).

Comment: @YashMalani: In [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2993834/315935) for example you will find a simple example. You can find a lot of examples by searching on the stackoverflow: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjqgrid%5D+resizeStop+) and [here are my old answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+%5Bjqgrid%5D+resizeStop+).